# Windows keep overlapping with dock when maximized

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

After I updated Ubuntu to 22.04 I've started experiencing this annoying behaviour where application windows randomly overflow their width and slip beneath the dock; that area becomes invisible and forces me to minimize and maximize again. This never happened to me with previous versions of the OS.

I'm attaching a screenshot to show you what I mean.

Does anyone know what it could be? Thank you for your help!

[image: Gnome Terminal beneath dock]

Comment: Have you tried setting the Preferences in Terminal? Hamburger menu > Preferences > Unnamed > Text tab > Text Appearance and try different options on columns and rows

Comment: @24601 I think that those apply when the window is minimized, changing them do not seem to have any effect in my case

Comment: not exactly. Works for me changing the settings on different size monitors in other than minimised.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and I can confirm it is annoying :-)

Comment: At the same time, my windows often end up too high, so that the bottom of the window extends below the screen edge. I have to unmaximize the window, drag the window down a bit so I can get a resize handle, then make it shorter and drag the window back up again.

Comment: It's a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1961508 Here's a workaround: https://github.com/popov895/dash-to-dock-workaround

Answer (score 1):

### Resetting Ubuntu Dock to Default Settings

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/
```

to get back to the default Ubuntu Dock state, you can reset all of the associated properties:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock activate-single-window
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-1
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-6
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots-border-width
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide-mode
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock shift-click-action
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock animate-show-apps
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-2
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-7
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots-color
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-monitors
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock shift-middle-click-action
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock animation-time
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-3
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-8
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-shrink
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock shortcut
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock apply-custom-theme
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-4
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-9
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dash-max-icon-size
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock max-alpha
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock shortcut-text
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock apply-glossy-effect
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-5
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-10
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock middle-click-action
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock shortcut-timeout
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-1
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-6
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock minimize-shift
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-2
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-7
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide-in-fullscreen
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock min-alpha
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-delay
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-3
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-8
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock background-color
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock force-straight-corner
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock multi-monitor
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-favorites
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-4
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-9
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock background-opacity
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock height-fraction
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock preferred-monitor
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-5
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-10
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock bolt-support
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hide-delay
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock pressure-threshold
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-running
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-6
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-1
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hotkeys-overlay
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock require-pressure-to-show
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-show-apps-button
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-7
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-2
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock customize-alphas
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hotkeys-show-dock
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock running-indicator-dominant-color
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-trash
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-8
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-3
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-background-color
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock running-indicator-style
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-windows-preview
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-9
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-4
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-customize-running-dots
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock icon-size-fixed
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-ctrl-hotkey-10
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-5
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots-border-color
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-switch-workspace
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock unity-backlit-items
```

related:

1. [get back to the default Ubuntu Dock state.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241726/1698042)
2. [How to Reset Ubuntu Dock to Default Settings](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/06/reset-ubuntu-dock-default-settings)

Comment: For those who are frustrated with this situation re-occuring:  This is an unresolved bug in Ubuntu 22.04, 22.10 and 23.10 and it hasn't been fixed yet.... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1961508